# What is the Russian word for a suicide committed by a warrior to restore honor?

Tags: одним-словом

I would like to know the Russian word for a suicide committed by a warrior when he failed at his duties or wanted to avoid being captured, with the suicide motivation being to restore honor for himself and his family.

I recall reading about General Alexander Samsonov, who committed a suicide following the military disaster at Tannenberg, and I vaguely recall reading about some other Russian officers who, like Samsonov, committed a suicide in relation to "честь офицера."

I know that the general Russian word for a suicide is "самоубийство," but I want to learn a more specific term reflecting what I described above. I was unable to find any such Russian word on my own.

Comment: There is no such word.

Comment: There only form of suicide accepted by russian moral - is to prevent enemies from getting military secrets , wich is not seemed as suicide, but as military action (like suicidial attack of last resort). All other form of suicides  are considred as sin, cowardice and betrayal of a God's will. It means that suiside is directly opposite to "restoring honor" for Russians.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Russian culture doesn't have a tradition similar to харакири/сэппуку. Servicemen were never obliged to rinse their dishonor with blood. To my knowledge there's no succinct term for this act.

There's a phrase **смыть позор / пятно позора / бесчестье кровью**. However it rather refers to restoration of one's good name by way of exceptional valor in the battle and not necessarily with death, suffering a wound is also a valid way to achieve that.

Comment: @Mitsuko There's definitely no specific word for this but it is considered a preferred option (among professional military men) to kill oneself in certain circumstances. Normally this is expressed with a full phrase like *застрелиться, чтобы избежать позора/бесчестья/плена* or *застрелиться от позора / не вынеся позора* (when *позор* already happened).

Comment: Other set phrases for committing a suicide are "покончить с собой" and "свести счёты с жизнью".